# Child theme is not getting parent theme's jQuery code in wordpress.

Tags: wordpress

Hey I have created tabbed menu in my wordpress blog. I have done it in parent theme. Now I have created a child theme of that parent theme. Everything seems fine expect tabbed menu. I have used jQuery for tabbed menu. 
Here is my `function.php` file's specific part to include jQuery and css code from parent theme.

```
// enqueue tabs script
function my_scripts_tabs() {
if ( !is_admin() ) {
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-tabs');
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-tabs', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 
'/js/tabs.js', array('jquery'));
}
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_tabs');

//add tabs stylesheet
wp_register_style('jquery-custom-style', 
get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.css', 
array(), '1', 'screen'); 
wp_enqueue_style('jquery-custom-style');
```

Here is my function.php file for child theme.

```
<?php
// Exit if accessed directly
if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;
// BEGIN ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION
// AUTO GENERATED - Do not modify or remove comment markers above or below:

if ( !function_exists( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css' ) ):
function chld_thm_cfg_parent_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent', trailingslashit( 
get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'style.css', array( 'genericons' ) );
}
endif;
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css', 10 );

// END ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION
```

Anyone please help. TIA

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit

```
get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.css'
```

to

```
get_template_directory_uri().'/css/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.css'
```

at parent theme. 
Because when it is run by child theme get_stylesheet_directory_uri() returns child theme path, although the code is in parent theme.